# Web API POST Method Replacing Plus (+) With Blank

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API that accepts parameters and if I put a plus character (+) in one of the parameters, when I retrieve the value, something (assuming .NET) has replaced that value with a blank ( ).  The exact example is where I'm accepting a phone number from an external system and it supplies the number with the included country code.  So, for US, the supplied value is "+12223334444" and when I get the value, it's " 12223334444".  Any idea what would cause this?

```
[Route("api/SMS/HandleResponse"), HttpPost, AllowAnonymous]
public TwiMLResult HandleResponse(string apiVersion, string smsSid, string smsStatus, string smsMessageSid, string numSegments, string from, string toState, string messageSid, string accountSid, string toZip, string fromCountry, string toCity, string fromCity, string to, string fromZip, string body, string toCountry, string fromState, string numMedia)
{
    // from is now " 12223334444" instead of "+12223334444"

}
```

Comment: the client needs to http encode the request before being sent.

Comment: Not directly related, but why aren't you using a DTO instead of so many parameters?

Comment: You have to encode `+` to `%2B` when inside query string before making the request, or else it will be decoded as a space (which is the expected behavior for [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp))

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'm using Twilio and have no control over what they send me.  I guess I could create a DTO that has these properties.  I might try that.

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out, there were two issues causing this problem.  First, I had a TON of NuGet packages that needed updating.  I'm not 100% convinced that this caused the problem completely, but after updating, it began to function properly again.  The second cause was that I was using PostMan and the way I was submitting the parameters (url args vs form-data).  After updating the NuGet packages and redeploying my API, it worked fine.